# Create a function that takes in a vector and returns a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am trying to create a function that will take in a vector k and return to me a matrix with dimensions length(distMat[1,]) by length(k).  distMat is a huge matrix and indSpam is a long vector. In particular to my situation, length(distMat[1,]) is 2412. When I enter in k as a vector of length one, I get a vector of length 2412. I want to be able to enter in k as a vector of length two and get a matrix of 2412x2. I am trying to use a while loop to let it go through the length of k, but it only returns to me a vector of length 2412. What am I doing wrong?

```
predNeighbor = function(k, distMat, indSpam){
  counter = 1
  while (counter<(length(k)+1))
  {  
preMatrix = apply(distMat, 1, order)
orderedMatrix = t(preMatrix)
truncate = orderedMatrix[,1:k[counter]]
checking = indSpam[truncate]
checking2 = matrix(checking, ncol = k[counter])
number = apply(checking2, 1, sum)


return(number[1:length(distMat[1,])] > (k[counter]/2))
counter = counter + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I could use cbind to bind some vectors together, but how can I create a vector, save it, and then put it into cbind?

Comment: What are the entries of the matrix? Your question is all about dimensions. Do you care if the matrix you get back is the right shape but filled with 0's? What is the relevance of `indSpam`? A `while` loop is certainly not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a function that will take in a vector k and return to me a matrix with dimensions length(distMat[1,]) by length(k)

Here's a function that does this.

```
foo <- function(k, distMat) {
  return(matrix(0, nrow = length(distMat[1, ]), ncol = length(k)))
}
```

If you have other requirements, please describe them in words.

Based on your comment, I think I understand better your goal. You have a function that returns a vector of length `k` and you want to save it's output as rows in a matrix. This is a pretty common task. Let's do a simple example where `k` starts out as `1:10`, and say we want to add some noise to it with a function `foo()` and see how the rank changes.

In the case where the input to the function is always the same, `replicate()` works very well. It will automatically put everything in a matrix

```
k <- 1:10
noise_and_rank <- function(k) {
    rank(k + runif(length(k), min = -2, max = 2))
}

results <- replicate(n = 8, expr = {noise_and_rank(k)})
```

In the case where you want to *iterate*, i.e., the output from the one go is the input for the next, a `for` loop is good, and we just pre-allocate a matrix with 0's, to fill in one column/row at a time

```
k <- 1:10
n.sim <- 8
results <- matrix(0, nrow = length(k), ncol = n.sim)
results[, 1] <- k
for(i in 2:n.sim) {
    results[, i] <- noise_and_rank(results[, i - 1])
}
```

What your original question seems to be about is how to do the pre-allocation. If the input is always the same, using `replicate()` means you don't worry about it. If the input is is different each time, then pre-allocate using `matrix()`, you don't need to write any special function.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear! I am inputting k into a function and I will be doing something to it and it will come out differently. I need to save that output vector, let the function run through each element of the vector, and save each output vector and construct it into a matrix.

Your answer was helpful in getting me to the right matrix format!
I tried putting my old return into the data portion of the matrix but right now, it is only giving me copies of my first output vector.

Comment: Edited to address your now-more-clearly-stated problem